# Returning NUMA Node 0 Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, numa

I have recently installed ubuntu 18.04 on my Laptop, having 8GB ram, 128 GB SSD, 1TB hard, and NVIDIA MX-110.

I installed Tensorflow 2.2 with CUDA and CUDNN (10.1 and 7.6.5 respectively). The output of

```sh
$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())"
```

is

```sh
WARNING:tensorflow:From <string>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2020-08-22 16:49:00.218791: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-08-22 16:49:00.243455: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 1800000000 Hz
2020-08-22 16:49:00.243773: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f48bc000b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-22 16:49:00.243798: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-22 16:49:00.245631: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272044: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272327: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x56105b3aa1e0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272346: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce MX110, Compute Capability 5.0
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272476: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272656: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce MX110 computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.006GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2020-08-22 16:49:00.272812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:49:00.274015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-08-22 16:49:00.275222: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-08-22 16:49:00.275443: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-08-22 16:49:00.276756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-08-22 16:49:00.277520: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-08-22 16:49:00.280247: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-08-22 16:49:00.280378: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.280622: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.280782: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-22 16:49:00.280816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281494: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281574: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281770: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:49:00.281952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 61 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce MX110, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
True
```

Now When i ran my jupyter notebook, and made a basic model,

```py
#JUPYTER NOTEBOOK CELL NUMBER 1
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
y = to_categorical(y)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

"""
JUPYTER NOTEBOOK CELL # 2
This code below takes almost 6,7 mins to run
"""

model1 = Sequential([
    Dense(512, activation='tanh', input_shape = X_train[0].shape),
    Dense(512//2, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(512//4, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(512//8, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
```

Main thing which i can see in terminal is

```sh
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

and Full terminal output is

```
[I 16:37:13.657 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 427db0cf-ee0b-49fa-b075-ce24cdc456bb:6564a2664692489a8473d40138e004c7
2020-08-22 16:38:17.412089: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-08-22 16:38:17.465067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.465381: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce MX110 computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.006GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2020-08-22 16:38:17.465580: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:38:17.467132: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.468592: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.468928: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.470530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.471467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.474846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-08-22 16:38:17.475036: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.475556: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.475947: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-22 16:38:17.476205: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-08-22 16:38:17.482259: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 1800000000 Hz
2020-08-22 16:38:17.482562: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fa670000b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-22 16:38:17.482589: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-22 16:38:17.510525: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.510905: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55b17c39ce70 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-22 16:38:17.510933: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce MX110, Compute Capability 5.0
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511104: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511357: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce MX110 computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.006GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511403: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511441: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511458: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511475: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511493: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511562: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.511828: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.512056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-22 16:38:17.512092: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513132: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513150: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513236: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-08-22 16:38:17.513756: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1461 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce MX110, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
```

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232898/memoryerror-in-tensorflow-and-successful-numa-node-read-from-sysfs-had-negativ) but I could not figure out anything.

Can someone please tell some easy solution to overcome this problem. Thanks.

### EDIT:

Output of NVIDIA-SMI is

```
Sat Aug 22 17:03:25 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX110       On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P5    N/A /  N/A |   1977MiB /  2004MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1069      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 15MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1200      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               46MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1481      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 91MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1655      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               77MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2042      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       80MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3620      G   ...token=4935481349596337741       32MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8276      C   ...nda3/envs/deep/bin/python     1624MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and output of
`nvcc --version` is

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MemoryError in TensorFlow; and "successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1)" with xen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232898/memoryerror-in-tensorflow-and-successful-numa-node-read-from-sysfs-had-negativ)

Comment: @Ahmad Anis , were you successful in fixing these warnings? I am facing the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Found a solution here, to suppress the warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611224/6587836